# Export to excel on vuetify data table

Tags: vue.js, export-to-excel, vuetify.js

the thing is i cant find how to export de data from this vuetify datatable to excel.

You can see the code and documentation here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#data-table

Answer (score 3):

There is no support to export data table to excel in vuetify.
Either you have do it manually or you have to use any other library or plugin for vue to export it.
This one seems like good option to do it.

https://github.com/dwqs/js2excel

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem with vue-json-excel, I leave the link in case it serves someone else https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-json-excel, thanks for the help!

Comment: @RobertOsses Thanks for the link - just wanted to let you know that this saved me quite some time in my development.

Answer (score 0):

[This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-excel-xlsx) has the same functionality but it's still maintained. I still don't know if it works with Vue3, though.