# Export data to excel on vuetify data table?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I am trying to export fake data not from api from datatable. but i am not getting any example regarding this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export to excel on vuetify data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534501/export-to-excel-on-vuetify-data-table)

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to export the table to a `csv` file would be using [vue-json-to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-json-to-csv).

```
<vue-json-to-csv
     :json-data="yourList"
     :csv-title="'fileName'"
>
     <v-btn color="success" class="mr-6">
          Export <i class="mdi mdi-export-variant" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </v-btn>
</vue-json-to-csv>
```

Answer (score 0):

watch this video i'm sure it will help any one who wants to export JSON data to excel and to import excel in JSON format, json to text, svc, or even pdf, although is not in English but it is easy

Used npm dependancies

> > read-excel-file

> > export-from-json

https://youtu.be/j0Z8FxXLctU

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.